# AngularJS beginner data binding confusion

Tags: data-binding, angularjs

I'm in the middle of trying to get my head around the data binding capabilities of AngularJS and have sort of a newbie question:

In the sample below, when I type a name into the textbox, the greeting doesn't update.

```
<html ng-app>
<head>
    <script src="js/angular.js"></script>
    <script>
        function myCtl($scope){
            $scope.person=$scope.fname;
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
        <div ng-controller="myCtl">
            <input ng-model="fname"/>
            <br/>               
            Hello, {{person}}
        </div>
</body>
```

When I change

```
Hello, {{person}}
```

to

```
Hello, {{fname}}
```

The greeting updates as I type. I'm confused about why the second syntax works but not the first.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To asgoth's answer I would also add that this code belies a misunderstanding:

```
$scope.person=$scope.fname;
```

This code is *not* run each time something happens in the view but only once when your controller is executed. You seem to be trying to set `$scope.person` to the value in `$scope.fname`. But `$scope.fname` is not defined - that's what your controller needs to do. Your view and controller are therefore both referencing an undefined value.

In a simple case like this your controller should just initialize your model when it starts:

```
function myCtl($scope){
    scope.person = {
        fname: '',
        lname: '',
        email: ''
    };
}
```

and you then bind elements to properties of person (e.g. `ng-model="person.fname"`).

Now, whenever code runs in your controller, it automatically has the correct `person.fname` angular takes care of that for you - you never need to "read from your view".

```
function myCtl($scope){
    $scope.person = {
        fname: '',
        lname: '',
        email: ''
    };
    function validate() {
        if (!$scope.email.match(/@/) return window.alert('Please enter a valid email address!');
    }
}
```

From your view you would then do:

```
<form ng-submit="validate()">
```

or

```
<button ng-click="validate()">
```

Answer (score 4):

`$scope.person=$scope.fname` creates a `person` primitive property on the $scope object and assigns it the value `undefined` (because $scope.fname does not yet exist when this line of code is executed).  This is what your $scope looks like before you type into the textbox:

[image: $scope before typing]

After you type something into the textbox, Angular automatically creates a `fname` primitive property on the $scope, and automatic two-way databinding continually sets the value to whatever is in the textbox.  So, if I type "Mark", then $scope now looks like this:

[image: $scope after typing]

It should be clear now why `{{person}}` shows nothing, but `{{fname}}` shows what is in the textbox.

Answer (score 2):

Because, when you are typing in the input field, `$scope.fname` is changing, not `$scope.person`.

You could fix it with a `$watch` on `fname`:

```
$scope.$watch('fname', function(value) {
   if(value) {
      $scope.person = value;
   }
}, true);
```